# How to find entry using name in eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel

By default we generally search any entry on db table by id number. But I could not find how to search any entry by the name column.

This is my code for finding entry and rendering it to view

Controller : Authors

```
class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_view($id){
        $authorModel = Authors::find($id);
        return View::make('authors.view')
            ->with('author', $authorModel)
            ->with('title', $authorModel->name);
    }

}
```

Model : Authors

```
<?php 

class Authors extends Eloquent {
    public static $table = 'authors';
}
```

Route :

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());

Route::get('author/(:any)', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'authors@view'));
```

View :

```
@layout('main.index')

@section('content')
<h1>{{$author->name}}</h1>

<p>
    {{$author->bio}}
</p>

<small>
    {{$author->created_at}} |
    {{HTML::link(URL::$base.'/authors/', 'Go back')}}
</small>
@endsection
```

How do i make the url as not to display id but to display the name of the post like

> some.com/category/name (instead of some.com/category/id)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your controller you are always going to search by `$id` as your Eloquent query uses:

```
$authorModel = Authors::find($id);
```

As your named route can be supplied with an int or string (:any) run a type check in the controller on `$id` and run a different query based on the result.

```
public function get_view($id)
{
   if (is_numeric($id))
   {
       $authorModel = Authors::find($id);
   }
   else
   {
       $column = 'name'; // This is the name of the column you wish to search

       $authorModel = Authors::where($column , '=', $id)->first();
   }

   return View::make('authors.view')
                ->with('author', $authorModel)
                ->with('title', $authorModel->name);

}
```

I hope that helps you.

As a side note, your Eloquent model.

There is no need for you to supply a table name if you use correct naming conventions.

```
class Author extends Eloquent {

}
```

Note the singular `Author` will map to a table called `Authors` automatically without any intervention from you.

Comment: does space between two words matter?

Comment: A little confused with the last bit, space between which words? The query string?

Comment: i mean  when we route through name then there is possibility of occurrence like something.com/hello there/hi there/

i meant those spaces

Comment: Could you tell me how does it didn't work with David Barker's answer?

Comment: @monk you don't use spaces ever in the URL. If you do you must always make sure it is urlencoded to take account of those spaces. Easier said than done in any framework that manages the url for you. (apologies for long delay)

Comment: @DavidBarker what if I don't want to find by Id ? For example, I have a user table with IDs, and I want to search to see if an email already exist, if yes, instantiate that user.